# prevent user from navigating inside Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

as I'm allowed to run a javascript line after the iframe loading

I executed this script

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {e.preventDefault();} 
// it makes the user navigating without issues
```

I tried this one

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {return '';} 
// it promot a confirmation message if the use will leave the page or not
```

any other solutions ?

Answer (score 1):

How about override the links' click event handler?

```
window.onload = function() {
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for(var i in links)
        links[i].onclick = function() {return false; };
};
```